# Sum or count only few/limited row from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a student mark table where i putted student marks by subject. I wanted to take sum of maximum 3 subjects for each student. And also wanted to see subject count or how many subjects mark entry exist on this table group by a student. This is my table structure.

```
students
----------------------
id |    name    | roll
----------------------
1  | Rahim      | 201
2  | Kalas      | 203
----------------------
student_marks
--------------------------------
id | student_id | subject | mark
--------------------------------
1  |    1       |   A     | 10
2  |    1       |   B     | 5
3  |    1       |   C     | 10
4  |    1       |   D     | 5
5  |    2       |   A     | 10
6  |    2       |   B     | 10
--------------------------------
my_expected_table
----------------------------------
student_id | student_name | sum
----------------------------------
1          | Rahim        | 25
2          | Kalas        | 20
----------------------------------
```

I am trying but can't understand how would i give limit on join table my sample query here

```
SELECT students.id as student_id,
       students.name as student_name,
       sum(student_marks.mark) as sum
From students
inner join student_marks on student_marks.student_id = students.id
Group by student_marks.student_id
```

the query output you know, it will show sum of all row. but i want like previous table "my_expected_table"

```
----------------------------------
student_id | student_name | sum
----------------------------------
1          | Rahim        | 30
2          | Kalas        | 20
----------------------------------
```

Comment: So, is the problem you're trying to solve that for student 1 (Rahim), you're actually summing up four, not three rows? If you limit it to 3 rows, which 3 do you want - The top 3 marks? The bottom 3 marks? The first 3 as ordered by subject?

Comment: actually now i wanted to get only three row now any three(top/bottom/any by order). I think if i know how to take three row then i may figure out how to sort or order :) . Thanks

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER to generate first 3 rows, and then you can easily to do it.

Comment: where will i use row number to generate first 3 row. can you tell me briefly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is painful to do in MySQL.  The best way uses variables:

```
select sm.student_id, count(*) as num_marks,
       sum(case when rn <= 3 then mark end) as random_3_sum
from (select sm.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = student_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := student_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from student_marks sm cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @s := -1) params
      order by student_id, id
     ) sm
group by sm.student_id;
```

Notes:

- I didn't both with the join to the student table, that is obvious to add.
- This defines 3 marks as "the 3 marks on the rows with the lowest id".  This is determined by the second `order by` key.

Comment: this code is going over my head as i am not good in in mysql sorry. Can you suggest me any resource to learn mysql to solve painful work. do you have any plan to solve it more easily.
Thanks

Comment: @rana7cse . . . If there were an easier way to write the query, I would have written it that way.